# Create `setTimeout` Loop In React Without Cyclic Dependencies

Tags: reactjs, settimeout, react-state-management

I have the following situation and don't know what's the best way to approach it.  I want a component with two states, `playing` and `items`, when `playing` is set to `true`, it should add a new item to `items` every second, where the new item depends on the content in `items` so far.  So my naive approach would be the following:

```
function App() {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const addItem = useCallback(
    function () {
      /* adding new item */
    },
    [items]
  );
  useEffect(
    function () {
      let timeout;
      playing &&
        (function loop() {
          timeout = window.setTimeout(loop, 1000);
          addItem();
        })();
      return function () {
        window.clearTimeout(timeout);
      };
    },
    [addItem, playing]
  );
  /* render the items */
}
```

(I could use `setInterval` here, but I want to add another state later on, to change the interval while the loop is running, for this `setTimeout` works better.)

The problem here is that the effect depends on `addItem` and `addItem` depends on `items`, so as soon as `playing` switches to true, the effect will be caught in an infinite loop (adding a new item, then restarting itself immediately because `items` has changed).  What's the best way to avoid this?

One possibility would be using a ref pointing to `items`, then have an effect only updating the ref whenever `items` changes, and using the ref inside `addItem`, but that doesn't seem like the React way of thinking.

Another possibility is to not use `items` in `addItem` but only `setItems` and using a callback to get access to the current `items` value.  But this method fails when `addItem` manipulates more than a single state (a situation I've encountered before).

Comment: If `addItem` makes use of `items`, as far as I can tell, it will use an outdated version of `items` if not updated in `useEffect` but I'll try in and report back!

Comment: also try using functional update form of setState where you  can 'specify how the state needs to change without referencing the current state'...ie, `setState(c => c + 1)`. Example in the docs somewhat similar to your scenario using this approach: 'setInterval callback executes once a second, but each time the inner call to setCount can use an up-to-date value for count (called c in the callback here.)'. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often

Comment: Yes, the functional update definitely works, but it becomes cumbersome when there is more than one state to manipulate.  Then maybe something like `setStateA(stateA => {let newStateA; setStateB(stateB => {newStateA = foo(stateA, stateB); return bar(stateA, stateB);}) return newStateA;})` would work, but I feel like React misses a `getState` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implements functional approach to setting state, while defining the function to invoke the same within useState to remove dependency. ultimately allows setInterval to be used which feels more natural for this case.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";


function App() {
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(true);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([1]);

  useEffect(
    function () {
      const addItem = () => (
          setItems((arr) => [...arr, arr[arr.length - 1] + 1])
      );
    

      setTimeout(() => setPlaying(false), 10000)
      let interval: any;
    
      if (playing) {
        (function() {
          interval = window.setInterval(addItem, 1000);
        })();
      }

      return function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
      };
    },
    [playing]
  );


    return (
      <div>
        {items.map((item) => (<div key={item}>{item}</div>))}
      </div>
    )

  }


render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-nwcgq7